# git merge overwrites all previous changes

Tags: git, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree, git-commit

I have 2 core branches:

```
-develop: used for development
-master: used to ship code to production
```

developers work from develop.

I recently merged the pink branch with the commit "user authentication" to develop and it overwrote everything. This particular commit contains a large new feature.

I've reset the current develop branch to a commit before this merge for the moment.

I'm not sure what to do next? I need to marge this pink branch but I'm not sure how?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you already merged it in but where unhappy with the result - what went wrong?, did you actually lose your develop changes or did the merge just not go as you expected? - i.e. do you think this is a git issue or is it just that the two branches break each other when merged?

Comment: To try the merge again, you can create a new branch where you have highlighted it `git branch test_merge` then `git checkout test_merge` and then try the merge again: `git merge <commit-hash for user authentication>`. This will put your new merge attempt on this new branch. Then you can see what the outcome of the merge is.

Comment: @code_fodder I merged the 'user authentication' branch into develop and all my previous code in develop disappeared. There were a couple of small conflicts which I fixed but I have no idea why overwrote everything. I'll try what you said..

Comment: When you do that can you collect all the output (normally the merge tells you what it is doing (removing, adding, modifying files...) - then you can add it to your question and point out what you think went wrong.

Comment: So I've manually merged everything together. Is it okay to delete the old 'develop' branch and rename the new 'test_merge' as 'develop'?

Comment: Yes, you can do pretty much anything you want to do locally no problem :) . To push the new develop branch up (if its not tracked) you will need to do something like: `git push origin develop` or better still `git push -u origin develop`, where the -u will set the upstream tracking for you so next time you can just use `git push/pull`...